# Sharepoint 2013 external list item limit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a sharepoint 2010 external list based on ECT. Database has around 6000 entries and i need all those entries, however, I am getting only 2000 entries in List.

I checked Items Throttletype value and it shows, Default : 20000 and Max : 1000000

Why am I still getting 2000 entries. where can I change this?

**Update**: This is about BDC throttle, List view threshold has nothing to do here.

Comment: Are you check Business Data Catalog throttle config or SharePoint list throttle?

Comment: I am talking about BDC throttle

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the level of permissions you have. You need to follow this article (if you are using SP 2010) to change the throttling level http://www.sharepointboco.com/performance-with-sharepoint-2010-large-lists-list-view-throttling/

or for SP 2013 this: http://stevemannspath.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-list-view-threshold.html

Comment: Thanks but This is about BDC threshold, not list threshold. Default value of 20K makes this obvious.